# How can I save the path to a frequently used directory in UNIX?

Tags: unix, cd

Is there a way to save the path to a frequently used directory in UNIX, so instead of having to manually cd /path/to/directory I can just enter a shortcut cd myFavoritePath ??

Comment: Why not just create an alias for "cd /directory" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define your favorite directories in CDPATH environment variable. It's a colon-separated list of search paths available to the cd command. You should specify not a directory you want to switch but parent directory.

Here is brief info about it: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch14_05.htm

For example you have three directories you work with frequently:

```
/home/user/scripts/favorite/
/var/log/
/var/lib/
```

add to your ~/.bash_profile (or another shell profile file you use) the next line:

```
export CDPATH=.:/home/user/scripts:/var
```

In the example below I just redefine CDPATH in shell for the current session

```
[user@server lib]$ CDPATH=.:/var:/home/user/scripts
[user@server lib]$ cd log
/var/log
[user@server log]$ cd lib
/var/lib
[user@server lib]$ cd favorite
/home/user/scripts/favorite
```

If you want use tab while execute `cd` you can install bash-completion http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/ but it's optional

Also do not forget `cd -` command for quick switching to previous working dir

Comment: Would you mind elaborating how to set the CDPATH so that I can select this as the right answer?

Comment: The primary gotcha with CDPATH is to ensure that the value starts with `:` or `.:` — otherwise, you're in, say, your home directory and want to go to your bin directory and you type `cd bin` but your CDPATH starts `/usr/local` and your `cd` therefore jumps to `/usr/local/bin` rather than your own `bin` directory.  By putting `:` at the start, you jump to `./bin` or your own `bin` directory before looking elsewhere.  Of course, if you can simply learn to type `cd ./bin`, but I prefer not to.  If you have `.:`, the shell will echo where you go; if you have just `:`, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add the directory path in ~/.bashrc

> vi ~/.bashrc

> export FAV_DIR1=''

The variables in `.bashrc` load into the environment on new session. So make sure to reboot.

Then you can visit the directory by something like:

> cd $FAV_DIR1

Comment: Also, make sure to choose a name the doesn't cause conflict!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. So, I made `go`, what allows you to easily save aliases for your favorite paths. And you can find it here: https://github.com/aledquin/go

I use an alias to call it as:

```
alias go='source $HOME/bin/go_dir.sh'
```

and here are examples:

```
go save home $HOME --> saves it in a local file $HOME/env/dir_map.$USER
go home            --> change directory to $HOME
go <TAB>           --> display options to use:
%delete      %help        %remove_all  %update      
%edit        %list        %save        home
go update home $newHOME --> update alias to $newHOME
go delete home     --> remove the line where the alias home was.
```

Also has the option of a favorite ROOT where you can move thru directories using keywords.

```
GOROOT=$HOME ; #by default
go tests example  => change directory to: $HOME/tests/unit_tests/example/
go lib Example.py => change directory to where you can find Example.py
                     in the sub directories of $HOME/lib/ getting till:
                     "$HOME/lib/python/Package/src/" where Example.py was found.
```

Hope this helps!